# How to unzip a password-protected archive created by Linux, using Java

Tags: java, android, passwords, unzip

I am working on an Android project recently and met an issue. I send a request to webservice and got a zip file with password protection. The zip file is create using the Linux command

```
zip -P 123123123123123123 test.zip test.txt
```

I want to unzip it with Java. Because there is no standard API support so I need a third library.

1. I have tried `winzipaes`, but it prompts that my zip file is not in the AES-256 format.
2. I cannot use `sevenzipjbinding`, it's too large.

Do you have any suggestion about this? Do you know what algorithm Linux used to encrypt the zip file?

Comment: Check this thread, it's dealing with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271569/android-how-to-unzip-a-encrypted-zip-file

Comment: why not use 7zip or peaZips' (both open source) console and extract it like that ?

Comment: Hi David, thanks your help .it's hard to include 7zip library in my app because it's very large(around 2MB). I will look at peaZip's .

Comment: Hi jayeff, I am trying zip4j now.

Comment: Finally, I resolve this issue with a third java library named "zip4j".

Comment: Please post an answer saying that you used zip4j and how (ideally with a few lines of example code). Don't edit an answer into your question.

Comment: Finally, I done with zip4j.

1.Download zip4j-1.3.1 and import it to project.
2. Sample Code:
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(YourZipFile);
if(zipFile.isEncrypted()){
Stringmap_Unzip_Pswd=YourPassword;   zipFile.setPassword(map_Unzip_Pswd);
}
zipFile.extractAll(Path of Destination);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I done with zip4j.

1. Download zip4j-1.3.1 and import it to project.
2. Sample Code:

   ```
   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(YourZipFile);
   if(zipFile.isEncrypted()){
      zipFile.setPassword(Password);
   }
   zipFile.extractAll(Destination);
   ```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Zip4j includes support for WinZip-style AES-256 encryption. See the 'examples' package for how to do that.

Comment: I am getting an error `Error: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: file header not found for given file name, cannot extract file`
Please help with the solution.